# Replacing word not contained in string wrapped in quotations (python)

Tags: python, regex, string, file-io, regex-negation

I'm trying to replace all words in a file expect those that are found in a string with quotes, for example if I want to replace all occurrences of 'word' with 'new':

Hello this is word, word is: "this part includes word!". Word can be anywhere in the quotes, "word", " ... word ...", etc...

^original should now be:

Hello this is new, new is: "this part includes word!". New can be anywhere in the quotes, "word", " ... word ...", etc...

I've tried doing this with regex substitution but can't seem to find a pattern that matches all cases. (eg. file_text = re.sub(r"(?<!-)\b%s(?<!-)\b"%i, j, file_text), where i is 'word' and j is 'new', looks at stand alone words so "word" would remain the same but " word" would change to " new" )

Comment: so you have like a dict of word replacements to make in a file?

Comment: Ya that's right! @rv-kvetch

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'("[^"]*")|\b(?<!-)word\b(?!-)', lambda x: x.group(1) or 'new', text)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex. You can split the string on quotes and change the word in the even chunks (the odd chunks are within quotes):

```
text = '''Hello this is word, word is: "this part includes word!". Word can be anywhere in the quotes, "word", " ... word ...", etc...'''

out = '"'.join(s if i%2 else s.replace('word', 'new')
               for i,s in enumerate(text.split('"')))
```

output:

```
'Hello this is new, new is: "this part includes word!". Word can be anywhere in the quotes, "word", " ... word ...", etc...'
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain this a bit more. I see why it works but I would not say it is immediately obvious why it works for this string and potentially why it does not work for `text = '''Hello this is word: "this part includes \"word\"!"'''`

Comment: @JonSG quotes cannot be nested, here the quoted parts are `this part includes ` and `!`, the escaping doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `text` as set in my comment is not a valid string or produces some error?

Comment: @JonSG it is valid, but identical to a variant without '\', and works as expected, no?

Comment: If run with your code, the result is : `Hello this is new: "this part includes "new"!"` Which may or may not be correct. I suspect it is not the answer that was expected, though I concede that nested quotes might be an edge case that can be ignored.

Comment: If the string was `aaa: "bbb"ccc"ddd"`, would you call it nested? ;) you're just being biased as you're human and want to have `"new"` being inside the quotes, it just isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241043/discussion-between-jonsg-and-mozway).

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work with a minor modification to include both single and double quotes: '"'.join(s if i%2 else s.replace('word', 'new') for i,s in enumerate(re.split('[\"|\']', text))). Strangely enough this works with test strings but does the reverse on my text file, i.e. it's replacing words in the quotes and not otherwise, but this may be an issue elsewhere in my code

Comment: @mozway in my case nested quotes should also not be replaced and I am assuming it is valid only for even number of quotes so that each open quote has a corresponding closing quote

Comment: @SainaKoukpari I believe it is not working on your test data because while this solution works, it is fragile with respect to ordering and balancing `"` characters.

Comment: @Saina the thing is that there is no such thing as "nested quotes" (with a single type of straight quotes). For nesting you need an opening and closing symbol. Did you test my code? Can you provide an example for which of doesn't work?

Comment: @mozway What are you talking about. Of course escaped nested quotes exist. I provided a test case where it does not work. The expected answer is `Hello this is new: "this part includes \"word\"!"`

Comment: If you have "broken" text, i.e. a quote is missing somewhere, there is no code that can easily do what you want. You'll need to grasp the context and fix the broken bit.

Comment: @JonSG the quotes in your example were NOT escaped, try `'"' == '\"'`. This is identical, how should the code tell the difference if the python objects are identical ;) Anyway, even if there were escaped quotes (in the sense that there are different kinds of double quotes), this has nothing to do with OPs likely problem of missing quotes.

Comment: It seems like solution to resolve such an edge case could be straightforward enough. If we replace `\"` character in text with something like else like `\'` at least temporarily, then try with this approach, I think it should work and not replace the inner part. Then once replacements are done, could then replace those special characters with a escaped quote `\"` again.